# Power BI: How to calculate the sum of one column only where another column equals a certain date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate the sum of a column (Target Spend), but only where the value of another column (Report Period) is the current month.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calculate function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax

You'd typically build your visuals from the grand total measure and filter by the current month, though.